# noob: display err_msg on page (pt. 2)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, error-handling, validation

I posted this yesterday, so I apologize if you responded and are frustrated at seeing this again!  But the form isn't working at all now, and I'd appreciate some help in solving this problem.

I have a form that sends data to a database, and requires validation.  Yesterday it was at least validating correctly, but today I can't even get it to hook to my action page correctly.  Here are the two pages:

Page w/ form:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $form_field =   array(  
                                'First_Name'                =>  '',
                                'Last_Name'             =>  '',
                                'Business_Name'             =>  '',
                                'Phone_Number'              =>  '',
                                'Web_Address'               =>  '',
                                'Email_Address'             =>  '',
                                'How_selling_product'           =>  '',
                                'Where_did_you_hear_about_us'   =>  '',
                            );
    foreach($form_field as $key => $value){$profiledata[$key]='';}              

    if(!empty($_SESSION['profiledata'])){   
        $profiledata    =   $_SESSION['profiledata'];
    }

    ?>

    [js]
    function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
      var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
        d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
      if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
      for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
      if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
    }

    function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
      var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;

      errors    += addValidation("req","first_name","- First Name is required.");
      errors    += addValidation("req","last_name","- Last Name is required.");

      for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) { test=args[i+2]; val=MM_findObj(args[i]);
        if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") {
          if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) { p=val.indexOf('@');
            if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
          } else if (test!='R') { num = parseFloat(val);
            if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number.\n';
            if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) { p=test.indexOf(':');
              min=test.substring(8,p); max=test.substring(p+1);
              if (num<min || max<num) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
        } } } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
      } 

      errors    += addValidation("req","security_code","- Security Code is required."); 

      if(!errors){
        errors += addValidation("valid_lastname","first_name","- Please enter valid First Name");
        errors += addValidation("valid_lastname","last_name","- Please enter valid Last Name");
        errors += addValidation("numhyphenbrace","phone number","- Please enter valid Phone Number");
        errors += addValidation("valid_url","web address","- Please Enter Valid Web Address");
        errors += addValidation("email","email address","- Please Enter Valid Email");

      }
      if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);
      document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
    }
    [/js]

    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="mailform" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('Name','','R','Business Name','','R','Email Address','','R','How selling product','','R','Where did you hear about us','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">
        <div style="color:#FF0000; text-align:center;"><?php if(!empty($_GET['err_msg'])){echo $_GET['err_msg'];} ?></div>
            <fieldset>
                        <legend>Contact form</legend>
                    <p class="first">
                        <label for="name">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="First Name" id="first_name" size="30" value="<?=htmlentities($profiledata['First_Name'])?>" />
                    </p>
                            <p class="first">
                        <label for="name">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Last Name" id="last_name" size="30" value="<?=htmlentities($profiledata['Last_Name'])?>" />
                    </p>                
                    <p>
                        <label for="name">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Phone Number" id="phone number" size="30" value="<?=$profiledata['Phone_Number']?>" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="email">Business Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Business Name" id="business name" size="30" value="<?=htmlentities($profiledata['Business_Name'])?>" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="email">Web Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Web Address" id="web address" size="30" value="<?=$profiledata['Web_Address']?>" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Email Address" id="email address" size="30" value="<?=$profiledata['Email_Address']?>" />
                    </p>            
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>                                                                          
                    <p>
                        <label for="message">Describe how you plan on selling this product</label>
                        <textarea name="How selling product" id="How selling product" cols="30" rows="4"><?=htmlentities($profiledata['How_selling_product'])?></textarea>
                    </p>    
                    <p>
                        <label for="message">Where did you hear about us?</label>
                        <textarea name="Where did you hear about us" id="Where did you hear about us" cols="30" rows="4"><?=htmlentities($profiledata['Where_did_you_hear_about_us'])?></textarea>
                    </p>
                            <p>
                                <img src="CaptchaSecurityImages.php?width=100&height=40&characters=5" /><br />
                        <label for="security_code">Security Code: </label><input id="security_code" name="security_code" type="text" />
                            </p>                
            </fieldset>
                <p class="submit"><button type="submit">Send</button></p>
                <input name="mailform_address" type="hidden" value="email@address.com" />
    </form>
```

Mailform.php success:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include("connect.php");

function valid_email($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

function is_url($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^((www)\.)?((\w+|[\d]?+)+(\.|\-)(\w+[\d]?+))+(\w)$/", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

function valid_phone($str)
{
    $Num = $str;
    $Num = ereg_replace("([     ]+)","",$Num);;
    $Num = eregi_replace("(\(|\)|\-|\+)","",$Num);
    if(!is_numeric($Num))
    {       
        return FALSE;
    }   
    else
        return TRUE;
}

$form_field =   array(  
                            'First_Name'                    =>  '',
                            'Last_Name'                     =>  '',
                            'Business_Name'                 =>  '',
                            'Phone_Number'                  =>  '',
                            'Web_Address'                   =>  '',
                            'Email_Address'                 =>  '',
                            'How_selling_product'           =>  '',
                            'Where_did_you_hear_about_us'   =>  '',
                        );
foreach($form_field as $key => $value){$profiledata[$key]=trim($_POST[$key]);}

$_SESSION['profiledata']    =   $profiledata;

$emailto = NULL;
$emailmessage = "Dealer Contact Form\n";
$emailsubject = "Dealer Contact Form";

if(!empty($_POST)){

    //echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);die;

    if( $_SESSION['security_code'] != $_POST['security_code'] || empty($_SESSION['security_code'] ) ) {

        // Insert your code for showing an error message here
        $err_msg    = 'Sorry, you have provided an invalid security code';
        header("Location: reseller.php?err_msg=".urlencode($err_msg));
        return;

    } else {
        unset($_SESSION['security_code']);  
    }

    $fname      =   html_entity_decode(trim($_POST['First_Name']));
    $lname      =   html_entity_decode(trim($_POST['Last_Name']));
    $company    =   html_entity_decode(trim($_POST['Business_Name']));
    $phone      =   html_entity_decode(trim($_POST['Phone_Number']));
    $website    =   html_entity_decode(trim($_POST['Web_Address']));
    $email      =   html_entity_decode(trim($_POST['Email_Address']));
    $notes      =   "Lead Source: ".html_entity_decode(trim($_POST['Where_did_you_hear_about_us']))."\n";
    $notes      .=  "Selling Method: ".html_entity_decode(trim($_POST['How_selling_product']));

    if(!valid_phone($phone)){
        $err_msg    = 'Please enter valid Phone Number.';
        header("Location: reseller.php?err_msg=".urlencode($err_msg));
        return;
    }

    if(!is_url($website)){
        $err_msg    = 'Please enter valid Web Address.';
        header("Location: reseller.php?err_msg=".urlencode($err_msg));
        return;
    }

    if(!valid_email($email)){
        $err_msg    = 'Please enter valid Email.';
        header("Location: reseller.php?err_msg=".urlencode($err_msg));
        return;
    }

    if(!stristr($website,"http://") && !stristr($website,"https://") && $website){
        $website    =   "http://".$website;
    }

    $res    =   mysql_query("SELECT in_customer_id FROM tbl_customer WHERE st_company_name = '".addslashes($company)."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($res)){   
        $err_msg    =   'Business Name already exists';
        header("Location: reseller.php?err_msg=".urlencode($err_msg));
        return;
    }

    $res    =   mysql_query("SELECT st_user_name,st_user_email_id FROM tbl_admin_user WHERE st_user_email_id='".addslashes($email)."' AND flg_is_delete=0");
    if(mysql_num_rows($res)){   
        $err_msg    =   'Email already exists';
        header("Location: reseller.php?err_msg=".urlencode($err_msg));
        return;
    }

    $sql_customer   =   "INSERT INTO tbl_customer (`st_company_name`, `in_customer_type`, `st_customer_account`, `in_customer_phone_number`, `flg_customer_account_type`, `flg_disable_ordering`,  `st_message`, `in_status`, `dt_added_date`, `st_web`, `st_notes`) VALUES ('".addslashes($company)."', '2', '".time()."', '".addslashes($phone)."', '0', '1', 'You are an Inquiry customer', '0', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', '".addslashes($website)."', '".addslashes($notes)."')";

    mysql_query($sql_customer);
    $cust_id        =   mysql_insert_id();

    if($cust_id){
        $sql_user       =   "INSERT INTO tbl_admin_user (`st_user_first_name`, `st_user_last_name`, `st_user_company_name`, `st_user_email_id`, `in_customer_id`) VALUES ('".addslashes($fname)."', '".addslashes($lname)."', '".addslashes($company)."', '".addslashes($email)."', '".$cust_id."')";
        mysql_query($sql_user);

        $msg    =   "";
        $sub    =   "Thank you for contacting us.";

        ob_start();
        include("mailformat.php");
        $msg =  ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $headers    =   ''; 
        //$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";               
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: " . $_POST['mailform_address'] . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $_POST['mailform_address'] . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Bcc: email@address.com";

        if (@mail($email, $sub, $msg, $headers))
        {
            session_unset('profiledata');
        }
    }

    foreach($_POST as $name => $value)
    {
        if ($name == 'mailform_address')
        {
            $emailto = $value;
        }
        elseif($name    !=  "security_code")
        {
            $emailmessage .= $name . ": " . $value . "\n";
        }
    }
    session_unset('profiledata');
}

?>

    <?            
        if (@mail($emailto, $emailsubject, $emailmessage))
        {
        ?>
<p>We'll be in touch within two business days.  If you haven't heard back from us within two business days, please <a href="contact">contact us</a></p>
    <?
        }
        else
        {
        ?>    
<p>E-mail could not be sent. Please <a href="contact">contact us</a>.</p>   
        <?
        }
        ?>
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: note: this is a WordPress site.  The [js][/js] tags are being used with a plugin that allows js on pages.

Comment: Do you have any idea of what code changes were made between the time it was working and now? I know this seems obvious, but I thought I'd ask. I know it's sometimes hard to identify what may have changed. If you are not using some form of source control, I would recommend it. like github or SVN etc. I know this doesn't answer your question, but I hope it helps in the future :)

Comment: No, @M3NTA7, I can't find any change to the code.  And I haven't implemented any WP or plugin updates.  I've also scanned the FTP folders' dates to see if any change occured in any files and could find nothing...good thoughts, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit that I haven't read your code thoroughly, but any of these might be your problem:

1. In the call to `MM_validateForm()` in your script, I think you need to pass the names of your HTML form fields but though every argument seems correct, the first one is 'Name' that doesn't seem to be a valid form field.
2. What is the function `addValidation()` in `MM_validateForm()` and what does it do? Since I do not see its definition, I assume it might be generating errors in your JS.
3. In `MM_validateForm()`, after line no. 3 & 4, it seems that the variable `errors` is never empty and thus preventing your form to submit?

I'm not very clear at which point are you stuck - is your form not submitting at all? Did you try to do an alert of `errors` variable at the end of `MM_validateForm()`. Perhaps it might help.

Comment: The form wasn't submitting before, but now at least it's validating the errors in the url of `mailform.php`.  I did find one mistake that I was making - `action="mailform.php"` needs to be `action="mailform"`, and I've made the change in the code above.  So - now I have error validation in the url, but I'd like it to appear on the form page when they hit submit.  I'm sorry, I'm not very good at php or js - I'm just trying to maintain this code.